# Confusion in Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not much familier with Excel, So i am getting some confusions in understanding
certain formulas in excel sheet so can any one try to answer my question--
What is the meaning of the following formulas can anyone please elaborate them:

```
1.        =Fees!$D$9
2.        =IF(B16>0.7,Fees!$E$10,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For =Fees!$D$9, the word following the `=` sign is a name of a worksheet. In this example, the worksheet name is `Fees`. `!$D$9` is a reference to the cell D9 in worksheet Fees. Using this notation, you can make the value of a cell equal to any other cell in the workbook.

=IF(B16>0.7, Fees!$E$10, 0) is the IF formula. It means that if the value in the cell B16 is greater than 0.7, then set the value of the cell to the E10 cell of the worksheet Fees. If not, set the value of the cell to 0.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

The first formula simply sets the cell value equal to the value of the cell `D9` on the worksheet `Fees`. The syntax is `WorksheetName!CellAddress` - the dollar signs `$` in the cell address simply mean absolute rather than relative, i.e. don't change the source cell when you copy the formula to other destination cells.

The second sets the cell value equal to the value of the cell `E10` on the worksheet `Fees`, unless the value in cell `B16` of the current worksheet is less than or equal to `0.7`, in which case it sets the cell value equal to `0`. Here the syntax is `IF(Predicate, Value if predicate true, Value if predicate false)`.

Comment: @ShashikumarMisal if you have found this or other answers useful, you should consider up-voting them rather than commenting - see ["What should I do when someone answers?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
=Fees!$D$9
```

This returns cell D9 from a sheet named "Fees"

```
=IF(B16>0.7,Fees!$E$10,0)
```

This checks if the value in the cell B16 in the current sheet is larger than 0.7 or not. If it is larger then it returns the cell E10 from a sheet named "Fees". Else it returns the value "0"

Answer (score 1):

Formula 1 is an absolute reference to cell D9 on the worksheet called Fees.

Formula 2 makes use of the `IF` function to return a value conditional on whether the value in cell `B16` is greater than 0.7. If the value in `B16` is indeed greater than 0.7, then the function returns the value in cell E10 on the worksheet called Fees. Otherwise, it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Fees` is sheet name. Default sheet name is like sheet1, sheet2 etc.
   In this case `Fees` is name of the sheet renamed.
2. ! symbol after `Fees` is syntax used to identify `Fees` as sheet
   name. the $D is column and $9 is row. `$` symbol before a column and/or
   a row makes it absolute reference.
3. The if function takes care of else part also. So, the function will
   return the value in cell `Fees!$E$10` if condition is true other
   wise it will return 0.